# Figure out if Android application was installed via web Market or using Android Market app

Tags: android, google-play

Right now when user wants to download an application, he can do it using Android Market application installed on his phone or do it via web Market.

Is it possible to figure out, which way was this application installed ?

Comment: from installed app point of view or from app's publisher account on market ?

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: miałem na myśli punkt widzenia aplikacji, czyli, czy chcesz to sprawdzić w aplikacji. druga opcja: czy chcesz te dane wydobyć z konta, na którym publikujesz aplikacje... o ile w drugim przypadku, możliwe jest, że Google gdzieś to zapisuje o tyle w pierwszym przypadku nie wydaje mi się by było to możliwe

Comment: @Selvin I want to check in my application if it was installed via web - if so, then I would to execute some part of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this in the [Android Cracking Blog](http://androidcracking.blogspot.com/2011/01/anti-cracking-example.html):

```
private boolean InstalledFromMarketEasy() {

 String pname = this.getPackageName();
  PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
  String installPM = pm.getInstallerPackageName(pname);

  if ( installPM == null ) {
    // Definitely not installed from Android Market
    return false;
  }
  else if ( installPM.equals("com.google.android.feedback") ) {
    // Installed from the Android Market
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

According to the comments however, on some phones this does still return null.

Try this method to see if it returns null with your phone. If it doesn't, have a look if `installPM` changes when using Android Market Vending instead of the WebInterface.

If it doesn't change, I don't think it is possible to check how it was installed, as the Push-Notification is received by Vending.apk.

Comment: Thank you for this example and this blog - it's nice. I was affraid that it will be a bit painful to solve this issue.

Comment: I will not tell you it right now. When I will have an opportunity, I'll give you some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Better it should be

```
else if ( installPM.equals("com.android.vending") ) {
        // Installed from the Android Market
        return true;
      }
```